# ViewBinder modifies only one item in all ListView rows

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, simplecursoradapter, android-viewbinder

I have a `ListView` that's populated from a `SimpleCursorAdapter` each row containing 3 different `TextViews`. I only want to modify one of the `TextViews` for all rows with a `ViewBinder` (`R.id.text65`), however it keeps updating all 3 `TextViews` of every row. Here's my code:

```
cursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            sign = (TextView) view;
            SharedPreferences currency = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            String currency1 = currency.getString("Currency", "$");
                    sign.setText(currency1);

                    return true;
        }
    });
```

P.S. I tried `(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text65);` and I got a `Force close`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You should check the column index in the `viewbinder`:

```
       public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
           if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(**??**)) // 0 , 1 , 2 ?? 
            {
               sign = (TextView) view;
               SharedPreferences currency = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                String currency1 = currency.getString("Currency", "$");
                    sign.setText(currency1);

                    return true;
             }
             return false;
        }
```

Note, the column index, is the DBcolumn index of the currency / the index of the column in whatever is your data source.

**Solution 2:**

You are probably defining an `int[]` for the fields to bind to in your `listview` for example :

```
            // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.field1, R.id.field2, R.id.Currency };

    SimpleCursorAdapter entries = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
```

...  Conditionally, you can simply pass `0` instead of the layout ids of the fields that you donT want to be bound / shown.

```
            int[] to = new int[] { 0, 0, R.id.Currency };
```

This way only the Currency field will be bound.

---

Also, the reason you get the *force close* is because, technically, there is no *single* `text65` in your *contentView* but *many*. You cannot access it from the main layout level. It is unique only in the scope of a single row.

---

**Update :**

**Solution 3:**

Check the `id` of the view in the `ViewBinder`

```
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        int viewId = view.getId();
        Log.v("ViewBinder", "columnIndex=" + columnIndex + " viewId = " + viewId);
        if(viewId == R.id.text65)
        {
            sign = (TextView) view;
            SharedPreferences currency = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            String currency1 = currency.getString("Currency", "$");
            sign.setText(currency1);

            return true;
         }
         return false;
     }
```

Could you try this?

Useful hint: you can use the `Log.v` to check certain values in your code without having to debug it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is all very great information thank you, however let me be a little more specific about the situation. In my listview, each row contains a date, an expense, and a currency symbol with that expense that can be changed in the settings.                      (Ex.[June 19  $102.32]). These solutions would work great if my currency symbol was located in my database, but its just a simple value located in sharedpreferences that I want duplicated in every row. Thank you again for your time

Comment: So whats happening is my listview rows show up as [$ $ $] because its changing all 3 of the textviews. If you have a solution for this I would be grateful!

Comment: hmm.. You should be able to use the first solution tho. isntead of `cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(...)` try hardcoded values (0, 1, 2) and do simple tests to see if you can get the currency column set.

Comment: I tried numbers 0-10 but it kept returning false....ugh I wish I was smart and knew about this stuff

Comment: it s weird.. I ve suggested another approach for you to try.